# how to remove "Request method 'GET' not supported' error from the screen in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, get, http-method

When i access the URL api in the browser, i get this error in the screen:

Request method 'GET' not supported

What i want is to completely remove this error when i access the url directly in the browser.
i tried creating a exception handler logic to catch the error and display a blank text but it does not work

here is my code:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;

@controllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMethodNotAllowedExceptionException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex){
   
      return new ResponseEntity<>("",HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);

   }
}
```

Is there a way to remove this error from the screen? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An alternative would be to create a dummy GET method and have it do as you want.  Not perfect but it's very unclear why you want to have it be handled at all.

Comment: what is want is just to not display the error in the screen whenever user access any api url in the application

Comment: If such is the case, need to add dummy GET handler in controller

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 3.2, this code works perfectly:

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> exceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
}
```

If your project doesn't pick `GlobalExceptionHandler`, it means that there are discovery problems or you have another `ExceptionHandler` bean somehow overrides that handler. 
Make sure you updated project to the latest versions and `GlobalExceptionHandler` class in package that is discoverable for spring.

For example if app defined like that:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Make sure you put `GlobalExceptionHandler` class into `com.example.demo` package or it's sub packages.